# Map only specific type with Automapper

Tags: c#, automapper, automapper-3

```
public class Destination
{
    public decimal Obj1 { set; get; }
    public decimal Obj2 { set; get; }
    public int Obj3 { set; get; }
}

public class Source
{
    public decimal Obj1 { set; get; }
    public decimal Obj2 { set; get; }
    public decimal Obj3 { set; get; }
}
```

how can I map `Source` class into `Destination` , but only `Decimal` types with Automapper ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use conditional mapping for this:

The following example will only map properties with source and destination type decimal. You can define your mapping like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
                .ForAllMembers(s=>s.Condition(t =>t.SourceType == typeof(decimal) 
                                               && t.DestinationType == typeof(decimal)));
```

And then use the mapping like this:

```
  var src = new Source();
  src.Obj1 = 1;
  src.Obj2 = 2;
  src.Obj3 = 3;
  var dst  = Mapper.Map<Destination>(src);
```

The dst variable will now have only the Obj1 and Obj2 properties mapped. Obj3 is 0 (default value of an int).

Not sure if this is exactly what you mean. Maybe you only want to check source property type or destination property type, but i hope you get the point.

The above is a generic approach which will still work if more properties / types are getting added to the classes.

Comment: How do you do it for only one member?